# Streaming issue in android

Tags: android

I have streamed audio from url,but when the call or sms comes i need to pause the song and when the call ends again i am gonna resume the song...

How to do this?...

Comment: What have tried so far?  What isn't working?

Comment: FWIW, you can look at the source code for the built-in music player and see what they did. At first glance, I don't actually see ANYTHING they did there, other than listening for AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=tree;f=src/com/android/music;h=3d3b699833ee91dee46f6443e313012f9c8fe704;hb=HEAD

Comment: i just streamed from url and playing the song and i want to extend the functionality , when incoming call comes ,just pause the song...

Comment: The thing is - the built-in music player pauses on incoming calls. That's why I recommended looking at the source code. (ADUIO_BECOMING_NOISY is triggered when you plug in or unplug a headset, so I doubt that's it. But that's the only relevant thing I saw when quickly skimming the code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works in my app, it's pretty simple. In your `onCreate()` put this code to listen for phone events and then act appropriately:

```
          TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
        PhoneStateListener ringListener;

        // Get the telephony manager
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        // Create a new PhoneStateListener
        ringListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

          @Override
          public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            String stateString = "none";
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
              stateString = "Idle";
              break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
              stateString = "Off Hook";
              break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
              stateString = "Ringing";

            Log.i(TAG, "TELEPHONE RINGING!!");                          

              //Do stuff here when phone ringing detected


            break;
            }
           }
        };

        // Register the listener with the telephony manager
        telephonyManager.listen(ringListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


        //End create a new PhoneStateListener
```